# BASH : Assigning sed result in an array on shell script

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I used the sed function to exact the values from a XML file but I'm stuck on how to assign it to a array.

This is the sed code

```
sed -n 's|<url>\(.*\)</url>|\1|p' filename.xml
```

The result is

```
VALUE1
VALUE2
VALUE3
VALUE4
```

How to assign these values to an array?

Thank you

Comment: Not an answer, but somewhat related - you might get some use out of http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/, makes shell scripting with XML a little more reliable.

Answer (score 6):

Put the values inside `(...)` in an assignment:

```
IFS=$'\n' array=($(sed -n 's|<url>\(.*\)</url>|\1|p' filename.xml))
```